# Jquery table onclick events

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have A function in jquery which goes to a php file, which querys a database returns the results in a table with a button in each row, 
how do i access the buttons in the page that the jquery is on. here is some code

```
//function to get table form php file with button on each row
function show(str)
{

$.post('INCLUDES/gettable.php',{club: str},
    function(output)
    {

        $('#box').html(output).show();
    });

}
 //when button from table is clicked do something
   $("button").click(function()
  {
      alert("hello");
   }
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: you're missing ); at the end of your click handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `live()` or better `on()` (comes with latest version of jQuery) for dynamically generated html/data:

```
$("button").on('click', function()
{
  alert("hello");
}
```

Or

```
$("button").live('click', function()
{
  alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: i have done this but for some reason it only works with .live, can you tell me why thats happening by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're loading the tables rows in dynamically, so they won't be part of the dom at page load.

you should use the .on() function to get access to these - see [jQuery API docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)